# Module not found: Can't resolve '../components'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created `components` folder in the root of the project so it looks like this now:

```
project
 |______components
 |          |___________Sidebar.jsx
 |______pages
          |___________index.jsx
```

And this is the top of my `index.jsx` file:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Sidebar from '../components'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
```

And I get the error: `Module not found: Can't resolve '../components'`

The Sidebar component is very simple:

```
function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="container flex w-20 h-20 bg-red-600">
        Hey
    </div>
  )
}
export default Sidebar
```

What am I missing? Maybe some basic React imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a file name at the end. `import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'`